# Chrome/Chromium alternative for the Firefox “Self-Destructing Cookies” extension

Tags: chrome, privacy, cookies

I am looking for a new extension for Chrome/Chromium similar to [Self-destructing cookies](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/self-destructing-cookies/) in Firefox.

[In this Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/592164/is-there-a-chromeium-alternative-for-the-firefox-self-destructing-cookies-ex), an answer was validated suggesting [**Tab Cookies**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-cookies/iahecghojagkcoehfhfknajofkokndjm). This extension seemed to fit the bill at the time (delete both cookies and local storage data whenever all tabs from one domain were closed). Unfortunately it seems to have stopped working. More precisely, I have checked the cookies with CCleaner after closing the browser, and they were still there, along with local storage.

As a temporary solution I have set up the browser to delete all cookies when closed, but it is not completely satisfactory.

Answer (score 3):

beforehand: no, there is not!
there can't and won't be any real equivalent for chrome(ium) until [this 7 years old bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=78093) is solved... maybe google calls it internally a feature. :-(

--> so if there is any extension for chromium based browsers which claims to be a replacement for *Firefox*+*Self-Destructing Cookies* and - to be more precise - therefore clears also LocalStorage, i would get skeptical.

---

nonetheless, since [*Self-Destructing Cookies*](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/self-destructing-cookies/) got discontinued due to the API-changes there are replacements at least for Firefox:

1. the easiest replacement seems to be [**Cookie AutoDelete**](https://github.com/Cookie-AutoDelete/Cookie-AutoDelete): it cleans cookies and LocalStorage after closing tabs and (optional) domain change within the tab. it also supports gray- & white-listing with ex- & import.
   beside its [extension for firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/cookie-autodelete/) it also provides a [extension for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookie-autodelete/fhcgjolkccmbidfldomjliifgaodjagh), but not with exactly the same features because of the mentioned restrictions.
2. and also [**Forget Me Not**](https://github.com/Lusito/forget-me-not/) seems really good and interesting, but i would recommend it for more advanced users since it has a bunch of more detailed options.
   it is only [available for firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/forget_me_not/) since it is questionable how useful such extensions are for chrome(ium)...

Answer (score 1):

**My Review of Vanilla Cookie Manager**
Someone mentioned above that Vanilla Cookie Manager was their best choice.  I have used this extension for a very long time and I know all the ins and outs.  I think it's a really awesome extension although it has one big drawback that I will mention later in this review.  Due to this drawback, I will let you know who this extension might be good for and who it might not be such a great fit.  This is a *very* simple program that's very easy to learn and very easy to use.  That's a huge plus when so many extensions take weeks or months to learn.  Here, all you have to do is click the exension icon once in a while.  Also, I can assure you that it's not downloading anything malicious to your computer since it's such a simple program.

**Purpose of This Extension**
This program simply creates a whitelist and blacklist of websites in which you allow all cookies to work for the websites on the whitelist and you block all cookies for the websites on the blacklist.  That doesn't mean that only cookies on the whitelist will work.  Cookies that are not on any list will work in addition to the cookies that are on the whitelist.

However, at the end of the day when you close your browser, the browser will completely erase all the cookies from websites that are *not* on your whitelist.

What this does is 3 things the next time you load your browser.  First, the websites on the whitelist, you don't have to login nor do you have to set any preferences again.  That's such an awesome and convenient feature.  If you visit gmail.com a lot, you don't have to log in, you don't have to set any colors or arrangements or anything else that you would prefer.  It's all already set up from the last time you visited the site.  And, if you change anything, the cookie will not that and the next time you log in, it will remember what you changed.

So, do you see why you would want to keep cookies?  If you trust a website fairly enough and put it on your whitelist (you put it on your white list but simply clicking the Vanilla Cookie icon at the top right while you are visiting the website), then, every time you visit the website, you don't have to go through the miserable process of logging in, trying to remember your password, and typing it in.  You'll already be logged in right away as you gave permission to stay logged in!  (This won't work for websites like banks.)  And, as I said before, all your personal preferences will be activated.

If a website is *not* on your whitelist or blacklist, you'll have to press the OK dialog again when they ask if they can use cookies while you are using their website.  Then, you also have to once again manually log in (if you don't have a password manager which is a pain in the butt as we all know).

If the website is on your blacklist (it's called "Sites with unwanted cookies"), your browser will block all cookies from being saved to your computer.  This is important because some websites (actually probably most websites) use cookies to track your movements on the web and other invasions of your privacy.  Some rare cookies might even have maleware inside them that can really mess up your computer.  (It's happened to me recently and I had to reinstall my Windows 10.  What a pain in the butt!)  So, I wil put some website that look really shady in the list called "Sites with unwanted cookies".

**Who is this Extension Best For?**
This extension is largely targeted for people who don't know too much about computers or what cookies are.  That are also for simple people who don't care they are being tracked and don't want to waste a lot of time to constantly relogging into a website they constantly use.  This is a great extension for these types of people.  Say you visit Canvas.com a lot since that's your go-to design website and you trust it.  You should whitelist it so that whenever you go to Canvas.com, you're already logged in and the site is personalized for your likes and dislikes.  It will show you designs that you showed preference for the last time you were there and show designs that are more likely suited to your tastes.

Another example is Google.com.  Without cookies, Google.com will show results that aren't personalized at all.  If you look up "designing meth", it might show you websites describing the natural sources of methane gas.  But, with your personalized cookies saved, it will know to show you results on how to create meth from household ingredients in your kitchen to create methamphetamine for recreational use.  You see the difference that cookies make?  (I'm *totally* joking about searching up methods to cook meth from a kitchen lab in your home to sell on the streets.  Please don't do this!)

For the website that you didn't whitelist, you can choose a few options with this extension.  You can have the browser completely delete all cookies not on the whitelist after a few minutes, every time you log in, etc.  Or, you can have the browser just keep all cookies (except the ones on the blacklist) and make sure the ones on the whitelist are never erased by accident.  I would just delete all cookies that are not on your whitelist every time your restart your browser.

For example, I'll never whitelist a website like tabloid newspapers, websites that ask for a slew of personal information like your location (you just know they are definitely selling your info), and other websites of the same ilk.  Yet, I still whitelist sites I know that are going to track me like Google.  You know they are going to get your info anyway since we are so highly integrated into their products.  So, why not just whitelist them and make your life easier?

**Who This Extension is Bad For**
I would not advise this extension for people who are more knowledgeable and are willing to be a little more pro-active on what types of cookies you want and don't want to allow when you visit a website.  For example, there are cookie managers that will allow you to automatically relog onto a specific website but won't permit other types of cookies on that same website.  You have to pick and choose which one you would like to keep and block.  You pick and choose the cookies you want on each website you visit.  I've used these extensions for a long time as well.  I have to admit, it gets a little tedious.  It gets faster and faster as time goes by because it remembers your cookie selection for all the websites you visit.  So, when you visit the same website, everything will be all set.  But, sometimes it's a pain due to the effort and loss of time in order to figure out what to allow and what not to allow for a new website.  I wish website developers were just honest!

I'm a little anal and I don't like people tracking me and getting a perfect profile of what type of person I am - what websites I visit, what I like to eat, what I wear, where I live, etc.

So, I always web surf with a VPN with a constantly changing IP address and use Chrome with extensions that tries to block my identification.  For example, did you know that websites can do what is called Canvas Fingerprinting.  They can figure out who you are by the type of computer you use!  How?  Well, each computer actually is fairly unique with respect to the combination of CPU it has, the model/make of their graphics card, model and make of other computer components, what extensions you are using, etc.  You would think that a lot of people would have the same canvas fingerprint as you but actually, this is not the case.  So webpages can figure out who you are with this method and then web owners pool the information to figure out where you've gone and where you've been and what you've done.  Basically, know your entire profile.  What can you do?  There are extensions that will try to thwart this.  It will produce canvas "noise" that makes the canvas fingerprint different every time you log into a different website.

So, if you want to go to this length to hide who you are and what you do, you can see that it takes a lot of time and effort.  A lot of people think it's worth it.  Sometimes I do and sometimes I don't.  I flip back and forth.

In any case, as a beginner, you should definitely start with this extension first to learn what a cookie is and what it does.  Don't start with the complicated ones first.  You'll be totally clueless.  Then, after a few months, you can start to progress to the more complicated cookie managers, selecting what you want the website owners to know about you.

***I give this extension a 5 out of 5 for beginners.  A great extension.***

**StackExchange Promise**
I promise to readers that this is an objective review.  I have no stake in this program or any other cookie managers.  I don't knowingly have any friends or family that have a stake in any cookie managers.  With this said, if I'm not an objective write, I can get sued for a lot of money.

I also wanted to plead with other readers to PLEASE write a detailed review on just ONE extension, app, or program.  It'll probably take you an hour or so.  But, it will help everyone and you also.  If everyone just writes 1 very detailed review of a program that they have a lot of experience with, then this website would be a TREASURE TROVE, full of reviews that can really help people determine the *best* software in each category.  So, I beg on my knees to please write 1 detailed review if and only if you know a lot about a specific program.  Thank you!

Comment: Hi John!  Your plea is well written, valuable, and helpful, but not really suitable in an answer.  Would you mind creating an issue with your plea in the Meta for this SE and then remove the plea from this answer?

Comment: It's really not exactly perfect for this section?  I thought it would be perfect since this stack is about software recommendations.  So, this gives a perfect review of Vanilla Cookie Manager.  Who it would be good for and who would it be bad for.  If eventually several people reviewed each software deeply several times, you would know exactly which software is the best.  For example, there are a lot of reviews of softwares online but they reallly stink.  It's so hard to really find which software truly is the best.  Let me know what you think.  I'll move it if you still think the same way.

Comment: Ah, my note was not sufficiently clear.  My apologies.  When I wrote "your plea", I was simply referring to your first paragraph that begins with "StackExchange Plea!".  Your answer itself is truly excellent and definitely belongs right here! :)  Upon further thought, I still think your plea is worthy of being added to Meta, but I am also comfortable leaving it here as well.  I leave it to your discretion.

Comment: Ah, I get ya'! I'll remove the plea. Can I attach it at the end? I want to present my "dream"- a stack filled with awesome unbiased reviews that are located nowhere else. People might also get excited and start contributing just 1 really good review. I've realized that it's impossible for 1 person, even a pro writer, to know which software really is the best in a specific field. It takes too long and is too tedious to try every program. I'm speculating that's why we don't ever see such detailed articles (unless it's secretly written by a biased developer).

Comment: Thanks John. Personally, I'm good with it. I aspire to be as flexible as possible. If the community objects, however, it will be best to remove it. But as I'm the only one who has commented so far, we can just play it by ear.  If you post your plea in our community's meta forum (https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/), it will be on-topic and get additional exposure.  Thank you for your excellent answer!

Comment: You are one of the nicest and best moderators. IMHO, most moderators abuse their powers; it really irritates users so that they leave this site. We really don't need the aggravation esp when we just want to help. It's bringing this site down, I think. You really present your suggestions in a very friendly way that doesn't make the other person feel like he's being made to feel like your bixxh. It's like cops who go on power trips and bark orders to bystanders. Guys instintively push back. Anyway, just wanted to say you are doing a great job.

Comment: John, I sincerely appreciate your feedback. I believe that kindness is humankind's greatest lost art form and that we will all benefit if we choose to make it *en vogue*. Being kind is a choice that each one of us can make hundreds of times every day.  We regularly receive the gift of opportunity to be kind to others and to ourselves.  My biggest challenge is being kinder to myself, and I am actively working to rise to that challenge.  You have my thanks and appreciation.

Comment: You must be surrounded by a great group of co-workers and friends. This will sound really depressing and cynical. (I've had a really rough work day,) I think that nearly all people are just so selfish. I rarely see any kindness and it seems almost everyone is a taker (emotionally or monetarily). My wife says that giving is its own reward but I can't see it. I feel like I'm always the one always giving and I feel totally drained. How do you deal with it? You seem like you have such a sunny disposition. Were you born like this?

Comment: In most ways, I have not had an easy life. But from my struggles and pains, I have grown a little. I hope I have much growth ahead of me. I surely have ample opportunities, but finding the wisdom to move forward represents a significant challenge for me. Like you, today was a really rough day for me. If you would like to talk more, we can continue our conversation outside of these comments. Perhaps we can learn from each other.

Comment: Sure.  Send me a private message.  You can tell me your life story and I'll tell you mine!  :)

Comment: Sounds good, John. I'll make the popcorn. :)  It will likely be at least a few days, as I'm putting out multiple fires (not literally... hopefully!) every day right now.  I look forward to taking a break from all that and writing to you.

Comment: Actually, same here!  I am going crazy right now because people are yelling at me left and right.  Take your time...

Answer (score 0):

the best alternative for me is "Vanilla Cookie Manager".
Does everything I need and works just fine.

Link:
[Vanilla Cookie Manager - chrome web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vanilla-cookie-manager/gieohaicffldbmiilohhggbidhephnjj?hl=en-US)

Comment: You need to say why this is a solution to the problem - Don't juist dump a link with an opinion. Too put it bluntly: it's fine that it *Does everything I need*, but does it do what the OP needs?